# Fill in webforms / auto login in AutoHotKey in Crome

Tags: google-chrome, webforms, autohotkey

I want to open a couple of webpages. Some require User-name password. Others requires to fill in certain files in a webpage.

There are multiple ways for AutoHotKey to fill in web forms, but all are based on "com" which only works with IE

I've googled a while for examples in what fill in webforms and/or login in Crome, but found non so far. Does anyone has an example of an AHK script what fill in fields in a webpage/form

Answer (score 1):

First off I'm going to start by stating that you should have included code, after all this is a code review site rather than a "Hey I need codez" site...

Now to answer your question:

You are correct, COM Objects are the best way to interact with Websites in Windows, it's dead simple and just works (in IE). Since Chrome doesn't support COM, you are left with only working with within the limitations of the browser accepting keystrokes.

Your best shot is to use the Send command to navigate to your target field (I believe sending Tab multiple times when the window is active should work) and than Send the data you wish.

I would also suggest looking into #IfWinActive and BlockInput so that you won't accidentally send an inappropriate key stroke while filling in these forms.

There may be better options for this, such as KeePass or the like. Also it's generally not a good idea to store passwords in plain text, IE within an AHK Script.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, it's not possible to use Com objects with Chrome, however [this site](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/64563-basic-ahk-v11-com-tutorial-for-webpages/) has a ton of entry level how-to's to get started with using the com object in IE. This includes how to send specific fields text (without using the send or sendinput commands), and how to triggers onclick events on existing elements (without clicking on them).

This was were I started when I needed to learn how to interact with the com object.

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/64563-basic-ahk-v11-com-tutorial-for-webpages/